# Add new object to existing array of objects jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexing

I have an array of objects (containing my stimuli) and a function (see extract below) that collects reaction times and 'pushes' all reaction times to a global variable.

```
var stim = [  {name:"A", path:".../a.jpg", type: P}, 
              {name:"A", path:".../a.jpg", type: T}, 
              {name:"A", path:".../a.jpg", type: I}
           ];

var reac_arr = [];

$(function(){ ...    var reac_time = t2-t1;
                     react_arr.push(reac_time);
            };
```

Now I want to add the variable with all my reaction times to stim as object "reaction".
So that in the end I have the reaction time, the type, the path, and the name for all my stimuli, something like this:

```
var stim = [  {name:"A", path:".../a.jpg", type: P, reaction: 123}, 
              {name:"A", path:".../a.jpg", type: T, reaction: 876},
              {name:"A", path:".../a.jpg", type: I, reaction: 725}
           ];
```

I tried:

```
stim.reaction = react_arr;
```

but that's not working.

I need this to analyse how reaction times differ across different types of stimuli. I found answers on this for java but these weren't helping for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `stim` and `reac_arr` follow the same ordering:

```
stim.forEach(function (s, i) {
    s.reaction = reac_arr[i];
});
```

This loops over the `stim` array and adds a `reaction` property whose value is the value at the corresponding index of the `reac_arr` array to each object.

Comment: Thanks James, brilliant idea.Unfortunately the order of the stimuli for the stim array is randomised. Thus ultimately I want to have a possibility to see the reaction time for each stimulus. Can you think of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Presumably you're accessing an object out of `stim` and using it to do some stuff and then calculate `reac_time`. If that's the case you should still have a reference to the object from `stim` and you can manipulate it directly.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `stim` is a Array of Object, so `stim.reaction = react_arr;` won't work as you expect because you are in fact updating the `reaction` property from your `stim` Array.

That you want is to update the `reaction` property from one of the Object in your `stim` Array. So you should use :

```
stim[index].reaction = react_arr;
```

where `index` is the index of the object you want to update in `stim`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something Like::

```
var reac_time = t2-t1;
var temp={name:"A", path:".../a.jpg", type: P, reaction: reac_time}
react_arr.push(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var stim = [  {name:"A", path:".../a.jpg"}, 
          {name:"A", path:".../a.jpg"}, 
          {name:"A", path:".../a.jpg"}
       ];
stim.pop({name:"A", path:".../a.jpg"});
stim.push({name:"A", path:".../a.jpg", reaction: 725});
```

you can iterate to get the result for all